# Database Schema vs. Data Structure

Tags: data-structures, database-schema

What's the conceptual difference between a database schema and any data structure, in general? Don't both convey the organisation of data for efficiency? Or am I mixing two completely different things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database schema is the logical view of the entire DB.

Data structures are the specific formats that are used to store data (File, array, trees, etc)

Another way to think of it is that a DB schema will contain various data structures.

Comment: But doesn't a database schema always contain tables?